# Get application data from iTunes using PHP

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have an application in appstore and advertising companies in Google AdWords and Yandex Direct. Users come to iTunes page from search and context ads using special link.

How do i get data from some Apple service to know how many people installed an app after coming by adv link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i didn't find any PHP solution to access iTunes Connect analytics and started to develop my own version: https://github.com/aokozlov/itunes-connect-php

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itc0f2481229) Reporter tool is recommended to pull iTunes Connect Financial and Sales data, it is written in Java.

There is also unofficial package in PHP that does the same:

https://github.com/mikebarlow/itc-reporter